# How to hide spinner(progress bar) after download complete?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, download, android-cardview

I'm working on a app that downloads files, I have recyclerview -> cardview (10-20 items), if you click on one the items 
the process to download the file begins, and at the same time i add a spinner to let user know that the download is in process
but I'm having problem canceling the spinner once the download is complete, because I don't know how to reference back an specific cardview 
on the recyclerview, do i need to pass the position of the card view, the spinner(progressbar) id ?

any help will be appreciated, thank you!

from my adapter class

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FirstLevelViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ItemsLevel2 currentItem = fItems.get(position);

        final String id             = currentItem.getId();
        final String name           = currentItem.getName(); 

        holder.id.setText(id);
        holder.ame.setText(name);   

        holder.fImageButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                holder.img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                downloadFile(name);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here I have all the code for the download

```
downloadFile(String name) {

}
```

Comment: can you show us your downloadFile code?

Answer (score 1):

```
    int downloadFile(String name) {
     if (finish) return 1;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////
public void onClick(View v) { 
                    holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                   if( downloadFile(name))==1{
     holder.spinner.setVisibility(!View.VISIBLE); 
    }
                }
```

Comment: Add a bit of explanation instead of just adding the code. Right now even I'm unable to understand what you've written.

Comment: I'm not sure about this: This code checks for download finish *on click*, hence whenever the user clicks the button again. Instead there should be an *active* notification that the download has finished, so the UI can dispose immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading file from server, so you should use **AsyncTask** and download your file in `doInBackground()` method, show your progressbar in `onPreExecute()` and close spinner in `onPostExecute()`.

```
 public class DownloadFileAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //show Progressbar
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            //downloadFile()
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //close spinner
        }

    }
```